# Scrapy: Parsing list items onto separate lines

Tags: parsing, xpath, scrapy

Tried to adapt the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609267/scrapy-how-to-separate-text-within-a-html-tag-element) to my issue but not successfully.

**Here's some example html code:**

```
<div id="provider-region-addresses">
<h3>Contact details</h3>
<h2 class="toggler nohide">Auckland</h2>
    <dl class="clear">
        <dt>More information</dt>
            <dd>North Shore Hospital</dd><dt>Physical address</dt>
                <dd>124 Shakespeare Rd, Takapuna, Auckland 0620</dd><dt>Postal address</dt>
                <dd>Private Bag 93503, Takapuna, Auckland 0740</dd><dt>Postcode</dt>
                <dd>0740</dd><dt>District/town</dt>

                <dd>
                North Shore, Takapuna</dd><dt>Region</dt>
                <dd>Auckland</dd><dt>Phone</dt>
                <dd>(09) 486 8996</dd><dt>Fax</dt>
                <dd>(09) 486 8342</dd><dt>Website</dt>
                <dd><a target="_blank" href="http://www.healthpoint.co.nz/default,61031.sm">http://www.healthpoint.co.nz/default,61031...</a></dd>
    </dl>
    <h2 class="toggler nohide">Auckland</h2>
    <dl class="clear">
        <dt>Physical address</dt>
                <dd>Helensville</dd><dt>Postal address</dt>
                <dd>PO Box 13, Helensville 0840</dd><dt>Postcode</dt>
                <dd>0840</dd><dt>District/town</dt>

                <dd>
                Rodney, Helensville</dd><dt>Region</dt>
                <dd>Auckland</dd><dt>Phone</dt>
                <dd>(09) 420 9450</dd><dt>Fax</dt>
                <dd>(09) 420 7050</dd><dt>Website</dt>
                <dd><a target="_blank" href="http://www.healthpoint.co.nz/default,61031.sm">http://www.healthpoint.co.nz/default,61031...</a></dd>
    </dl>
    <h2 class="toggler nohide">Auckland</h2>
    <dl class="clear">
        <dt>Physical address</dt>
                <dd>Warkworth</dd><dt>Postal address</dt>
                <dd>PO Box 505, Warkworth 0941</dd><dt>Postcode</dt>
                <dd>0941</dd><dt>District/town</dt>

                <dd>
                Rodney, Warkworth</dd><dt>Region</dt>
                <dd>Auckland</dd><dt>Phone</dt>
                <dd>(09) 422 2700</dd><dt>Fax</dt>
                <dd>(09) 422 2709</dd><dt>Website</dt>
                <dd><a target="_blank" href="http://www.healthpoint.co.nz/default,61031.sm">http://www.healthpoint.co.nz/default,61031...</a></dd>
    </dl>
    <h2 class="toggler nohide">Auckland</h2>
    <dl class="clear">
        <dt>More information</dt>
            <dd>Waitakere Hospital</dd><dt>Physical address</dt>
                <dd>55-75 Lincoln Rd, Henderson, Auckland 0610</dd><dt>Postal address</dt>
                <dd>Private Bag 93115, Henderson, Auckland 0650</dd><dt>Postcode</dt>
                <dd>0650</dd><dt>District/town</dt>

                <dd>
                Waitakere, Henderson</dd><dt>Region</dt>
                <dd>Auckland</dd><dt>Phone</dt>
                <dd>(09) 839 0000</dd><dt>Fax</dt>
                <dd>(09) 837 6634</dd><dt>Website</dt>
                <dd><a target="_blank" href="http://www.healthpoint.co.nz/default,61031.sm">http://www.healthpoint.co.nz/default,61031...</a></dd>
    </dl>
    <h2 class="toggler nohide">Auckland</h2>
    <dl class="clear">
        <dt>More information</dt>
            <dd>Hibiscus Coast Community Health Centre</dd><dt>Physical address</dt>
                <dd>136 Whangaparaoa Rd, Red Beach 0932</dd><dt>Postcode</dt>
                <dd>0932</dd><dt>District/town</dt>

                <dd>
                Rodney, Red Beach</dd><dt>Region</dt>
                <dd>Auckland</dd><dt>Phone</dt>
                <dd>(09) 427 0300</dd><dt>Fax</dt>
                <dd>(09) 427 0391</dd><dt>Website</dt>
                <dd><a target="_blank" href="http://www.healthpoint.co.nz/default,61031.sm">http://www.healthpoint.co.nz/default,61031...</a></dd>
    </dl>
    </div>
```

[Search again](/provider/)

**And here's my spider;**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from webhealth.items1 import WebhealthItem1

class WebhealthSpider(BaseSpider):

name = "webhealth_content1"

download_delay = 5

allowed_domains = ["webhealth.co.nz"]
start_urls = [
    "http://auckland.webhealth.co.nz/provider/service/view/914136/"
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    results = hxs.select('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]')
    items1 = []
    for result in results:
        item = WebhealthItem1()
        item['url'] = result.select('//dl/a/@href').extract()
        item['practice'] = result.select('//h1/text()').extract()
        item['hours'] = map(unicode.strip, result.select('//div/dl/dt[contains(text(),"Contact hours")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
        item['more_hours'] = map(unicode.strip, result.select('//div/dl/dt[contains(text(),"More information")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
        item['physical_address'] = map(unicode.strip, result.select('//div/dl/dt[contains(text(),"Physical address")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
        item['postal_address'] = map(unicode.strip, result.select('//div/dl/dt[contains(text(),"Postal address")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
        item['postcode'] = map(unicode.strip, result.select('//div/dl/dt[contains(text(),"Postcode")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
        item['district_town'] = map(unicode.strip, result.select('//div/dl/dt[contains(text(),"District/town")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
        item['region'] = map(unicode.strip, result.select('//div/dl/dt[contains(text(),"Region")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
        item['phone'] = map(unicode.strip, result.select('//div/dl/dt[contains(text(),"Phone")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
        item['website'] = map(unicode.strip, result.select('//div/dl/dt[contains(text(),"Website")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/a/@href').extract())
        item['email'] = map(unicode.strip, result.select('//div/dl/dt[contains(text(),"Email")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/a/text()').extract())
        items1.append(item)
    return items1
```

From here, how do I parse list items onto separate lines, with the corresponding `//h1/text()` value in the name field? Currently I'm getting a list of each Xpath item all in one cell. Is it to do with the way that I am declaring the Xpaths?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you are using `results = hxs.select('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]')` so

```
    results = hxs.select('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]')
    for result in results:
        ...
```

**will loop on one `div` only**, the first child `div` of `<div id="content" class="clear">`

Want you need is to loop on every `<dl class="clear">...</dl>` within this `//*[@id="content"]/div[1]` (it would probably be easier to maintain with `//*[@id="content"]/div[@class="content"]`)

```
        results = hxs.select('//*[@id="content"]/div[@class="content"]/div/dl')
```

Second, in each loop iteration, you are using absolute XPath expressions (`//div...`)

```
result.select('//div/dl/dt[contains(text(), "...")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()')
```

this will select **all** `dd` following `dt` matching the text content starting from the document root node.

Look at [this section in Scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths) for details.

You need to use relative XPath expressions -- relative within each `result` scope representing each `dl`, like `dt[contains(text(),"Contact hours")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()` or `./dt[contains(text(), "Contact hours")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()`,

The "practice" field however can still use an absolute XPath expression `//h1/text()`, but you could also have a variable `practice` set once, and use it in each `WebhealthItem1()` instance

```
        ...
        practice = hxs.select('//h1/text()').extract()
        for result in results:
            item = WebhealthItem1()
            ...
            item['practice'] = practice
```

Here's what your spider would look like with these changes:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from webhealth.items1 import WebhealthItem1

class WebhealthSpider(BaseSpider):

    name = "webhealth_content1"

    download_delay = 5

    allowed_domains = ["webhealth.co.nz"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://auckland.webhealth.co.nz/provider/service/view/914136/"
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        practice = hxs.select('//h1/text()').extract()
        items1 = []

        results = hxs.select('//*[@id="content"]/div[@class="content"]/div/dl')
        for result in results:
            item = WebhealthItem1()
            #item['url'] = result.select('//dl/a/@href').extract()
            item['practice'] = practice
            item['hours'] = map(unicode.strip,
                result.select('dt[contains(.," Contact hours")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
            item['more_hours'] = map(unicode.strip,
                result.select('dt[contains(., "More information")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
            item['physical_address'] = map(unicode.strip,
                result.select('dt[contains(., "Physical address")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
            item['postal_address'] = map(unicode.strip,
                result.select('dt[contains(., "Postal address")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
            item['postcode'] = map(unicode.strip,
                result.select('dt[contains(., "Postcode")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
            item['district_town'] = map(unicode.strip,
                result.select('dt[contains(., "District/town")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
            item['region'] = map(unicode.strip,
                result.select('dt[contains(., "Region")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
            item['phone'] = map(unicode.strip,
                result.select('dt[contains(., "Phone")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())
            item['website'] = map(unicode.strip,
                result.select('dt[contains(., "Website")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/a/@href').extract())
            item['email'] = map(unicode.strip,
                result.select('dt[contains(., "Email")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/a/text()').extract())
            items1.append(item)
        return items1
```

I also created a Cloud9 IDE project with this code. You can play with it at https://c9.io/redapple/so_19309960

Comment: Small typo in spider, third line needs to be `webhealth.items1 import WebhealthItem1` (couldn't edit it myself, minimum edit is 6 chars). Excellent explanation accompanying the code, most appreciated.

Comment: ah yeah, I used the standard `items.py` to test it. Fixing it in the answer.

Comment: Also realised `item['hours'] = map(unicode.strip, result.select('dt[contains(.," Contact hours")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract())` had to be declared as `hours = hxs.select('//dl/dt[contains(text(),"Contact hours")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract()` and then `item['hours'] = hours`. Slowly getting the hang of this.